# Dependency fails to compile in workspace but not in package

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, wgpu-rs

I'm trying to set up a simple rust-wgpu project based on the cube example. I got it to run as a simple package (test1, below), but when I put it into a package (edit: I meant workspace) (test2), one of its dependencies, wgpu-hal, fails to compile, seemingly because it doesn't pull in the metal crate. I am new to Rust/Cargo, am I missing something obvious here?

https://github.com/henryrgithub/test1
https://github.com/henryrgithub/test2

edit: When configured as a workspace, it tries to build 191 items, when built as a package 187, also in somewhat different orders. Here are the errors (partial, it overflows my terminal scroll and character limit here):

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:41:27
   |
41 |         Tf::Rgba16Uint => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:42:27
   |
42 |         Tf::Rgba16Sint => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SINT,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:43:28
   |
43 |         Tf::Rgba16Unorm => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:44:28
   |
44 |         Tf::Rgba16Snorm => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SNORM,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:45:28
   |
45 |         Tf::Rgba16Float => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:46:27
   |
46 |         Tf::Rgba32Uint => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:47:27
   |
47 |         Tf::Rgba32Sint => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SINT,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:48:28
   |
48 |         Tf::Rgba32Float => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:49:29
   |
49 |         Tf::Depth32Float => DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:50:37
   |
50 |         Tf::Depth32FloatStencil8 => DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT,
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:51:28
   |
51 |         Tf::Depth24Plus => DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT,
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:52:63
   |
52 |         Tf::Depth24PlusStencil8 | Tf::Depth24UnormStencil8 => DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT,
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R9G9B9E5_SHAREDEXP` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:53:29
   |
53 |         Tf::Rgb9e5Ufloat => DXGI_FORMAT_R9G9B9E5_SHAREDEXP,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:54:29
   |
54 |         Tf::Bc1RgbaUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM_SRGB` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:55:33
   |
55 |         Tf::Bc1RgbaUnormSrgb => DXGI_FORMAT_BC1_UNORM_SRGB,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC2_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:56:29
   |
56 |         Tf::Bc2RgbaUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC2_UNORM,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC2_UNORM_SRGB` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:57:33
   |
57 |         Tf::Bc2RgbaUnormSrgb => DXGI_FORMAT_BC2_UNORM_SRGB,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:58:29
   |
58 |         Tf::Bc3RgbaUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM_SRGB` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:59:33
   |
59 |         Tf::Bc3RgbaUnormSrgb => DXGI_FORMAT_BC3_UNORM_SRGB,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC4_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:60:26
   |
60 |         Tf::Bc4RUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC4_UNORM,
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC4_SNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:61:26
   |
61 |         Tf::Bc4RSnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC4_SNORM,
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC5_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:62:27
   |
62 |         Tf::Bc5RgUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC5_UNORM,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC5_SNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:63:27
   |
63 |         Tf::Bc5RgSnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC5_SNORM,
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:64:30
   |
64 |         Tf::Bc6hRgbUfloat => DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16,
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_SF16` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:65:30
   |
65 |         Tf::Bc6hRgbSfloat => DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_SF16,
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:66:29
   |
66 |         Tf::Bc7RgbaUnorm => DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM_SRGB` in this scope
  --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:67:33
   |
67 |         Tf::Bc7RgbaUnormSrgb => DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM_SRGB,
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:146:25
    |
146 |         Vf::Unorm8x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UNORM,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:147:25
    |
147 |         Vf::Snorm8x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SNORM,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:148:24
    |
148 |         Vf::Uint8x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_UINT,
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:149:24
    |
149 |         Vf::Sint8x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8_SINT,
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:150:25
    |
150 |         Vf::Unorm8x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:151:25
    |
151 |         Vf::Snorm8x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SNORM,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:152:24
    |
152 |         Vf::Uint8x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT,
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:153:24
    |
153 |         Vf::Sint8x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SINT,
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:154:26
    |
154 |         Vf::Unorm16x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UNORM,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:155:26
    |
155 |         Vf::Snorm16x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SNORM,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:156:25
    |
156 |         Vf::Uint16x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_UINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:157:25
    |
157 |         Vf::Sint16x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_SINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:158:26
    |
158 |         Vf::Float16x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16_FLOAT,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:159:26
    |
159 |         Vf::Unorm16x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SNORM` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:160:26
    |
160 |         Vf::Snorm16x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SNORM,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:161:25
    |
161 |         Vf::Uint16x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:162:25
    |
162 |         Vf::Sint16x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:163:26
    |
163 |         Vf::Float16x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_FLOAT,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:164:23
    |
164 |         Vf::Uint32 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT,
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:165:23
    |
165 |         Vf::Sint32 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32_SINT,
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:166:24
    |
166 |         Vf::Float32 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT,
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:167:25
    |
167 |         Vf::Uint32x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_UINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:168:25
    |
168 |         Vf::Sint32x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_SINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:169:26
    |
169 |         Vf::Float32x2 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:170:25
    |
170 |         Vf::Uint32x3 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_UINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:171:25
    |
171 |         Vf::Sint32x3 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:172:26
    |
172 |         Vf::Float32x3 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:173:25
    |
173 |         Vf::Uint32x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_UINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SINT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:174:25
    |
174 |         Vf::Sint32x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SINT,
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT` in this scope
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/auxil/dxgi/conv.rs:175:26
    |
175 |         Vf::Float32x4 => DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0609]: no field `color` on type `&_`
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/metal/device.rs:857:89
    |
857 |                 let (color_op, color_src, color_dst) = conv::map_blend_component(&blend.color);
    |                                                                                         ^^^^^

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> /home/no/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/wgpu-hal-0.13.2/src/metal/mod.rs:592:5
    |
588 | #[derive(Debug, Default)]
    |                 ------- in this derive macro expansion
...
592 |     samplers: Vec<SamplerPtr>,
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `_: std::default::Default`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Default` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0283, E0425, E0432, E0433, E0609.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0283`.
error: could not compile `wgpu-hal` due to 569 previous errors
```

Comment: Seeing the error itself would do wonders for pinpointing your issue.

Comment: "Not found in scope" usually means something is missing. Could it be a missing feature flag that wasn't tested?

Comment: @fiddling_junky this is a wild hunch: try putting `resolver="2"` under `[workspace]` in test2's Cargo.toml

Comment: nailed it @kmdreko, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@kmdreko is correct in that you need:

```
resolver = "2"
```

in the workspace `Cargo.toml` file as described in [the beginner's guide](https://sotrh.github.io/learn-wgpu/beginner/tutorial1-window/#using-rust-s-new-resolver).

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'll make sure to read that over, I was just working off of the rust book.

Comment: @fiddling_junky The wgu-rs guide is fantastic and well worth the read.